# Translating "I'm sorry for your loss"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the most natural way in Spanish to say "I'm sorry for your loss," as in what you would say to someone grieving over a departed relative or friend (or even the loss of a job)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The translation for that particular case (grieving) could be one of this:

> Mi más sentido pésame
>
> Mi más sincero pésame

Both are formal ways. The action of doing this is:

> Dar el pésame (to your friend who just loss his father for example)

A more informal way of doing this would be:

> Siento mucho tu pérdida
>
> Te acompaño en tu dolor
>
> Te acompaño en el sentimiento (thanks @Rellikiox)

Comment: I would add "Te acompaño en el sentimiento", it's very common.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate translation in my opinion would be *Lamento su/tu pérdida* (formal/informal)